# UrlEncode and Answer in a Typeform email notification

Tags: urlencode, typeform

We have a TypeForm which sends an email notification at the submit, including a form answer (value of a TypeForm input field) as url parameter, as in www.google.com?q=[ANSWER]

[ANSWER] must be urlencoded - for security reasons and because spaces break the link

How can this be done in TypeForm?

Comment: Hi,

I believe this is not doable at the moment with Typeform.
You could probably build your own notification system using typeform webhooks, or Zapier.